# Reconstitute a user from time machine

Tags: backup, time-machine, catalina

On OSX Catalina, I have deleted a user and did not set aside a backup. However, going back on Time Machine, I can find the user directory.

I am considering creating a new user with the same name as the old user, and then replacing the new user's directory with the old user directory from Time Machine. Are there other setting  or files from the old User I should also be restoring?

Is there a better way of doing this.